# Html.textboxFor not showing model property value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model class in my asp.net mvc application. In controller action I am passing model to view like this:

```
public ActionResult PlayAPI(string CallIDno)
{
    CallRecording callRecording = new CallRecording();
    using (ICallRecordingManager callRecordingManager = new ManagerFactory().GetCallRecordingManager()) {
        callRecording = callRecordingManager.GetAll().Where(c => c.CallIDNumber == CallIDno).FirstOrDefault();            
    }
    return View("PlayApi", callRecording);
}
```

In view I am using this:

```
<div class="flds-up">
    <div class="lft-txt">
        Call ID Number
    </div>
    <div class="new-fld">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CallIDNumber, new { @class = "textarea required email"  })%>
    </div>
    <div class="clear-n">
    </div>
</div>
```

But textbox is empty although db record has value. I can use Html.textbox but I want to use model binding

Comment: And what happens when you debug, and inspect `callRecording` in your action? Is it null? Is `.CallIDNumber` null?

Comment: of course there is this line in View `@model CallRecording`  ?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi I would suspect that's only usable in the Razor view-engine. OPs code doesn't look like it uses that view-engine.

Comment: what to i need to change ?

Comment: @J.Steen you right, I mean model binding in View file: `<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication.Models.CallRecording>" %>`